# Where can I find EPSG codes for UTM (e.g., 16001)

Tags: geotools

Is there a plugin or database that I would use to add the EPSG codes for UTM zones to geotools?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TBH I've never come across EPSG:16001 as a code for UTM - but epsg.io does list [it](http://epsg.io/16001) but the definition looks "odd" in that it is purely machine readable. It might be coming out of a more recent edition of the database, but there's nothing there to help work that out. You [could add it to the epsg.properties file](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/faq.html#q-how-to-i-add-my-own-epsg-codes) if you could work out the WKT string for it.

The codes I would normally use are [EPSG:32601](http://epsg.io/32601) (WGS84), [EPSG:26701](http://epsg.io/26701) (NAD27) both of which are in the GeoTools database and have good definitions.